# VI05 - Purchase order is locked by the same user

Tags: abap

I run transaction code `VI05` with a Freight Cost document. When I pick the  ​document and press F8, an error message occurs: "Purchase Order is already elaborated by user ABC". I mention that ABC is my user.

It seems that this PO is locked/unlocked many times during VI05 flow, but the last time I get this error (when ME22 is called).

Did anyone meet this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no ABAP question in here. If it's a full standard transaction, then the issue is with SAP code, did you first check the SAP notes and ask SAP support before posting the question?

Comment: is it a good Idea to dequeue the PO in a user exit?

Comment: There is SAP [note](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/583864) exists for this problem.

Comment: could you please give me the name of the note. I'm not authorized to see the link you provided. thanks.

Comment: @PetruCristea note title is "583864 - VI04 VI05 User &1 is already processing purchase order &2 &3".